# Clicking on download icon and another page should open that displays message and download should start

Tags: html

I am creating a website that has at top in home page download icon and when i click on that icon another page should open that displays message like thanks for download and after 2-3 seconds download should automatically start, how i did this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the page where you displays the message place `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url=/download url" />` in the `<head>` section. This will redirect the request to the download url after 3 seconds.

Comment: i use this using image to download as try but it shows me image on page after 3 seconds rather downloads it

Answer (score 0):

You need to prepare the download page and attach a timeout script to allow it to download after the 2-3 seconds.

on your icon add the onclick function like following code:

```
<img id="downloadBtn" onclick="window.open('<put link to the download page here>')" />
```

On your download page, add the script like code below:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Download page</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Thank you for downloading</h1>
<p>Your download will start in <span id="countdown">5</span> seconds</p>

<script type="text/JavaScript">
var countdown = document.getElementById("countdown");
var wait = 5;
var timeout = setInterval(function(){
    wait--;
    countdown.innerHTML=wait;
    if (wait == 0){
        clearInterval(timeout);
        location.href="<link to the download file goes here>";
    }
},1000);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```