# Download a pdf automatically when a webpage is opened

Tags: javascript, html

I want that as soon as my .html file is opened , a pdf starts to download automatically (support for pc , tablets, phones) . I am not sure what am I doing wrong ?
Thank you . Any sure short JavaScript is more than welcome

```
<a href = "/public/news.pdf" download> </a>
```

Comment: I think what you actually want is a http redirect from your `.html` url to the pdf.

Comment: @knightMahajan check my answer

Comment: As @Bergi said you can try `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url=/public/news.pdf" />` in this case it will work even without javascript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clicking on download icon and another page should open that displays message and download should start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27123889/clicking-on-download-icon-and-another-page-should-open-that-displays-message-and)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

**HTML**

```
<a id="downloadLink" href="news.pdf" download></a>
```

**Java Script**

Solution 1 :

```
<script> 
    window.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById('downloadLink').click();
    }
</script>
```

Solution 2: after 2 second

```
<script> 
    var downloadStartTime = setTimeout(function () {
       document.getElementById('downloadLink').click();
    }, 2000);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this simple solution

Answer (score 3):

window.onload function is that you are looking  for.

```
window.onload = function() {
  var url = "Your file url";
  var w=window.open(url, '_blank');
  w.focus();
};
```

This will help you

Comment: Its not been displayed publically , since I am kinda new to stack overflow , but its already upvoted !

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var downloadUrl = "your_file_url";
    setTimeout("window.location.assign('" + downloadUrl + "');", 1000);
});
```

using javascript

```
<iframe id="download_iframe" style="display:none;"></iframe>
<script>
function Download() {
    document.getElementById('download_iframe').src = "//somewhere.abc/somefolder/something.exe";
};
Download();
</script>
```

This way, your client will be asked whether to "Save" or "Run" the file.

Comment: KNIGHT MAHAJAN is looking for the javascript solution. The code helps if we are using jquery. anyway good answer.

Comment: Works aptly for me

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<html>
<body onload="myFunction()">
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            document.getElementById('a').click();
        }
    </script>
    <a href="./image.pdf" download="image" id="a"> <img     src="./image.pdf">
    </a>
</body>
</html>
```